# Ethernet Not Connecting to Switch

Tags: networking, home-networking, switch

Having some trouble connecting a switch to my home network

I have the modem running a line into the switch, then a second line out of the switch onto the wifi router.

The wifi works fine, however none of the remaining wired connections on the switch connect to the network. The connection light goes on, but the devices don't connect to the network.

Checking the router admin panel shows the only connected devices are on the wifi. Plugging the devices directly into the wifi router works as well, and the IPs show back up in the admin panel

What could be going wrong here when plugging the wires into the switch?

Comment: The router needs to be between the switch and the modem. Connect the modem directly to the router's WAN/Internet port, and then connect the switch to one of the router's LAN ports.

Comment: If that is the case, why is the wifi still working? It's only the wired connections that won't work

Comment: The wired connections also work when plugged into the router, while still having the switch in the middle,  between the modem and router

Comment: The WiFi and the ports on the router work because that's the router's local network. The modem assigns an external IP to the router, and then the router assigns local IP addresses to the devices that connect to it and uses NAT to allow those devices to share the internet connection. By placing the switch between the modem and the router, you're isolating it from the router's LAN.

Comment: I need to mount the router on the ceiling and was hoping to only run one wire out to it. Is there any way to accomplish this? It also weird, because I had a 5 port switch in the same location and things seems to be working, it wasn't until I plugged in an 8 port switch that the wired connections stopped (although it may have been pure luck as some devices were still plugged in the router)

Comment: Some modems have routers built in, so if you want to turn your old router into a simple wireless access point you could do that but it would take some reconfiguring. Assuming your modem has router functionality, you could place the switch between it and the other router and get a setup that should work.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that!